# Interceptor does not take effect on Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, interceptor

I try to put an interceptor on a servlet, but it seems nothing happen. But it does intercept when I put the same thing on an session bean. I am not sure whether I am doing the right thing, but my idea is just to do some permission checking for servlet in the interceptor.

Servlet definition: it does not interceptor, no exception though

```
@WebServlet("/getCurrentDatetime")
@CheckPermission("DEV")
public class DatetimeServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
```

`CheckPermission` definition:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface CheckPermission {
    @javax.enterprise.util.Nonbinding
    String value() default "";
}
```

Session Bean definition: this interceptor works just fine

```
@Stateless
@CheckPermission("DEV")
public class MyServiceBean implements MyService {
...
```

I am using Java 1.6 and GlassFish 3.

Comment: Interceptor is used in EJB only, so it will not work on servlets.

Comment: In addition to the comment from Sergio Michels, the "interceptor" for servlets is simply the servlet `Filter`, I'd suggest you used that.